# Can't call self variable defined in py file in kv file

Tags: python, variables, kivy

I'm having issues with sharing variables between the .py file and the .kv file in kivy.

Here is a bit of code before explaining my ask.

.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Test(BoxLayout):
    def myfunc(self):
        self.mytext = 'blabla'

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

if name == '__main__':
    MyApp.run()
```

.kv file

```
<Test>
    Button:
        text: root.mytext
```

If I run this, I have a Traceback that says that Test() has no variable named mytext, and that's normal, because my variable is self.mytext

But when I change the variable in .kv file with root.self.mytext, I have a Traceback which says that there is no variable 'self' in Test(), which is normal too.

So how can I call a self variable in my .kv file inside the Test() class? Or is there a way to share my variable into the 2 classes so I can use it later in the Test() class?

May I precise that when I do not make rules in the .kv file, and make the variable in the build it works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I run this, I have a Traceback that says that Test() has no variable named mytext, and that's normal, because my variable is self.mytext

Your understanding here is wrong, the variable isn't `self.mytext`, that line of code sets the `mytext` attribute of the `Test` instance. Accessing this as `root.mytext` is perfectly reasonable in the kv file.

Your issue is that you never call `myfunc` therefore you never set `self.mytext` to anything, therefore you get the errors you've seen.

Try putting `self.mytext = "initial value` in the `__init__` method of `Test` instead.